# Facing problem with image upload and executing sql queries in the back end in angular and node

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I have a signup page in angular , then it takes the details and the image and should route to the console page , but when I am using    `router.post("/signup",  multer({ storage: storage }).single("image"),(req, res, next) => {...`

in the backend, it only uploads the image and does not run the associated SQL queries, or route to the console page and when I use: `router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {..` , everything works fine  with routing ,

I tired to use  `app.use(multer({ storage: storage }).single("image"));` but it did not worked as no image is uploaded and only routing takes place

I am stuck at this for 2 days  Please help, I am attaching only the necessary code, of the front end and backend otherwise it would be very lengthy

The use case is on sign up I will be routed to the console page along with the pic in the images folder.

signup.component.ts :>

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RxwebValidators } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../Services/AuthService/auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  //styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted = false;
  public business_logoLInk = '';
  formData = new FormData();
  form = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z.s]{4,20}$'),]),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    business_name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z.s]{4,20}$'),]),
    image: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]), //Validators.pattern('/.(jpe?g|png)$/i')
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[*.!@$%^&])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,32}$'),]),
  });
    logo;
  constructor(
    //private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authServ: AuthService
  ) {}
 
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.authServ.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/console']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
    }
  }
 
  get email() {
    return this.form.get('email');
  }
 
  onImagePicked(event: Event) {
    if ((event.target as HTMLInputElement).files.length > 0) {
      var file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
      this.logo = file;
      this.form.patchValue({ image: file });
      this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
      //  this.formData.append('image', file);
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (Event) => {
        this.business_logoLInk = reader.result as string;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    let user = {
      username: this.form.value.username,
      email: this.form.value.email,
      business_name: this.form.value.business_name,
      password: this.form.value.password,
    };
    this.formData.append('username', user.username);
    this.formData.append('email', user.email);
    this.formData.append('business_name', user.business_name);
    this.formData.append('password', user.password);
    this.formData.append('image', this.logo);
    this.authServ.registerUser(this.formData).subscribe(
      // passing the data to the auth service
      (res) => {
        console.log(res),
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.token),
          this.router.navigate(['/console']);
      },
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }
}
```

signup.component.html works fine along with image preview, so I not uploading it.

In the Authservice :>

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  private _signinUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
  private _registerUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/signup';
  private _userProfile = 'http://localhost:3000/api/console';
 
  noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ NoAuth: 'True' }) };
  constructor(private _router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {}
 
  googleRegisterUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._signinUrl, user); ///formData
  }
  loginUser(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._signinUrl, user);
  }
  registerUser(formData) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._registerUrl, formData);
  }
 
  getUserProfile() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._userProfile);
  }
 
  postAdmin(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._userProfile, user);
  }
  deleteToken() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
 
  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
 
  getUserPayload() {
    const token = this.getToken();
    if (token) {
      // const payload = atob(token.split('.')[1]);
      // const userPayload = token.split('.')[1];
      //  return payload;
      console.log('token is present ');
      try {
        const payload = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
        console.log(payload);
        return payload;
      } catch (e) {
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
 
  isLoggedIn() {
    const payload = this.getUserPayload();
    if (payload) {
      console.log('payload is present');
      return true; //userPayload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;                           //true
    } else if (null) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

and finally backend api.js:>

```
// const mysql = require("mysql");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require("formidable");
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;
const app = express();
const multer = require("multer");
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var mySqlconnection = require("../model/db.js");
const mySqlCon = mySqlconnection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database Connection Successfull 3");
});
let Email;
// id : any ;
//-------------Verifying token ---------------------------------
//creating function to verify token at the back end :
function verifyJwtToken(req, res, next) {
  //   var token;
  if ("authorization" in req.headers) {
    token = req.headers["authorization"].split(" ")[1];
  }
  if (!token)
    return res.status(403).send({ auth: false, message: "No token provided." });
  else {
    jwt.verify(token, "secret key", (err, payload) => {
      if (err)
        return res
          .status(500)
          .send({ auth: false, message: "Token authentication failed." });
      else {
        req.Email = payload.email;
        next();
      }
    });
  }
};
//-------------------Verifying token ends here -------------------------------------------
//NOW ADDING MIME VALIDATOR AND MULTER ----------------------------------------
  const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    "image/png": "png",
    "image/jpeg": "jpg",
    "image/jpg": "jpg",
  };
 
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      let error = new Error("Invalid mime type");
      if (isValid) {
        error = null;
      }
      cb(error, "images");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const name = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-");
      const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      cb(null, name + "-" + Date.now() + "." + ext);
    },
  });
 
  // app.use(multer({ dest: __dirname + "/file/uploads/" }).any());
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("From Api route");
});
//creating the api for login user --------------------
//creating the api for google/login user 
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  //for google user 
  let googData = {
    id: req.body.id,
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    photoUrl: req.body.photoUrl,
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    authToken: req.body.authToken,
    idToken: req.body.idToken,
    provider: req.body.provider
  };
  let loginData = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };
  // previously working fine  
  //google post Api-------------------------
  if (googData.id) {
    //  !loginData.email changing to googData.email
    let date = new Date();
    let sql =
      "INSERT INTO tbl_user( social_id,user_name, user_email, social_photoUrl, first_name, last_name, social_authtoken,social_idtoken, type, created_at, updated_at) SELECT * FROM (SELECT \
            '" + googData.id + "','" + googData.name + "','" + googData.email + "','" + googData.photoUrl + "','" + googData.firstName + "', \
            '" + googData.lastName + "','" + googData.authToken + "','" + googData.idToken + "','" + googData.provider + "','" + new Date().getTime() + "' as created_at,'" + new Date().getTime() + "' as updated_at) \
            AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT user_email FROM tbl_user WHERE user_email= '" + googData.email + "' ) LIMIT 1";
    let query = mySqlconnection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
      console.log(sql);
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      }
      // res.send(results);
      console.log(results);
      let payload = { email: googData.email };     //Adding user_id
      let token = jwt.sign(payload, "secret key", { expiresIn: "120m" }); //Adding Expires in 
      res.status(200).send({ token });
    });
  } //Google post api ends here -------------------------
  //--User Login POST Api--------------------------------------------
  else {
    let date = new Date();
    let sql =
      "select * from tbl_user  where user_email = '" + loginData.email + "'";
    let query = mySqlconnection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
      console.log(sql);
      if (err) {
        throw err;
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (!results[0]) {
          res.status(401).send("Invalid Email");
        } else {
          bcrypt.compare(
            loginData.password,
            results[0].password,
            function (err, result) {
              if (result !== true) {
                res.status(401).send("Invalid Password");
              } else {
                console.log(loginData.email);
                //Adding here ----------------------------
                let payload = { email: loginData.email }; //Adding user_id
                let token = jwt.sign(payload, "secret key", { expiresIn: "120m" }); //Adding Expires in
                //-------------ends here 
                res.status(200).send({ token });
                // res.send(results);
              }
            }
          );
        }
      }
    });
    //User login Api ends here ----------------
  }
});
//----------------------------------------------------
//creating the POST api for register user --------------------
router.post("/signup",multer({ storage: storage }).single("image"), (req, res) => {   // upload.single("file"), multer({ storage: storage }).single("image")
// const file = req.file;
// console.log(file.filename);
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    req.body.username = fields.username;
    req.body.email = fields.email;
    req.body.business_name = fields.business_name,
    req.body.password = fields.password;
    // req.body.image = fields.image;
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
      let user = {
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        business_name: req.body.business_name,
        password: hash,
      };
      let date = new Date();
      let sql =
        "INSERT INTO tbl_user( user_name, user_email, type, created_at, updated_at,password) SELECT * FROM (SELECT \
          '" +user.username +"','" +user.email +"','CTLSIGNUP','" +new Date().getTime() +"' as created_at,'" +new Date().getTime() +"' as updated_at,'" +user.password +"') \
              AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT user_email FROM tbl_user  WHERE user_email = '" +user.email +"' ) LIMIT 1";
      let query = mySqlconnection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        //-----------------
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log(results.insertId);
          let Sql =
            "INSERT INTO tbl_business_details (user_id,user_email,business_name,created_at,updated_at) \
              VALUES('" +results.insertId +"','" +user.email +"','" +user.business_name +"','" +new Date().getTime() +"','" +new Date().getTime() +"');";
          let query = mySqlconnection.query(Sql, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            } else {
              console.log(user.email);
              let payload = { email: user.email }; //Adding user_id
              let token = jwt.sign(payload, "secret key", {
                expiresIn: "120m",
              }); //Adding Expires in
              res.send({ token });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
   
  });
});
//----------------------register user Ends here -----------------------------\
 
 
//creating a GET API for getting user profile :>
 
router.get("/console",verifyJwtToken, (req, res) => {      
  //
  //verifyToken,
  //   console.log(payload);
  let sql = "select * from tbl_user where user_email = '" + req.Email + "'"; // Email changed to req.Email
  let query = mySqlconnection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.send(results);
    }
  });
});
// GET API ends here ------------------------------
 
 
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: please add a console.log like : `router.post("/signup",multer({ storage: storage }).single("image"), (req, res) => {return console.log('hey');` to check if the route function is fired or not. if it's fired, then you should check if `formidable` and `bcrypt` is working or not (with `console.log`), then with `console.log(sql)` check what's the sql statement to figure out why it's not executing.

Comment: thannkyou @yaya for your reply , I did what you recommended, it seems formidable doesnot work with multer middleware